# raspbian wheezy: Package 'i2c-tools' has no installation candidate

Tags: raspbian, i2c

I just tried `sudo apt-get install i2c-tools` and got the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package i2c-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'i2c-tools' has no installation candidate
```

Naturally, I tried `sudo apt-get update` and again attempted to install `i2c-tools` only to end up with the same result.

It seems like `i2c-tools` should still be available because

```
$ cat Downloads/Packages | grep i2c-tools
Package: i2c-tools
Filename: pool/main/i/i2c-tools/i2c-tools_3.1.0-2_armhf.deb
Source: i2c-tools
Recommends: i2c-tools
Filename: pool/main/i/i2c-tools/libi2c-dev_3.1.0-2_all.deb
Suggests: fancontrol, sensord, read-edid, i2c-tools
Source: i2c-tools
Recommends: i2c-tools
Filename: pool/main/i/i2c-tools/python-smbus_3.1.0-2_armhf.deb
```

where `Downloads/Packages` is http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-armhf/Packages (see http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#Do_you_have_a_list_of_all_the_packages_in_the_Raspbian_repository.3F)

Some quick Googling make me try this

```
$ apt-cache policy i2c-tools i2c-tools
i2c-tools:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     3.1.1-1 0
        -10 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
        -10 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
     3.1.0-2 0
        -10 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main armhf Packages
        -10 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main armhf Packages
i2c-tools:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     3.1.1-1 0
        -10 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
        -10 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
     3.1.0-2 0
        -10 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main armhf Packages
        -10 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main armhf Packages
```

which also makes it seem like I should be able to install it.

edit: I'm not sure if this is helpful, but this is the version I'm running:

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspi 3.12.22+ #691 PREEMPT Wed Jun 18 18:29:58 BST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

@doh-nutz After trying `sudo apt-get update`, here's what I got:

```
$ apt-cache search i2c
pypy-smbus-cffi - This Python module allows SMBus access through the I2C /dev
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep "deb hxxp://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi"
deb hxxp://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```

(the `hxxp` was actually `http`, but I need 10+ rep to post more than two links)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sudo apt-get install -t wheezy i2c-tools
```

worked, and I have a feeling that

```
$ sudo apt-get install -t jessie i2c-tools
```

would have also worked.  I guess `apt-get` was confused as to which Debian source I wanted to use, so it gave a somewhat unhelpful error message.

(Credit goes to http://somewideopenspace.wordpress.com/2014/02/28/gcc-4-8-on-raspberry-pi-wheezy/ for suggesting to me what to do.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this (after `sudo apt-get update`):

```
apt-cache search i2c
```

For me the output is (among others):

```
i2c-tools - heterogeneous set of I2C tools for Linux
```

In my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, i have the following line (maybe you're missing some of the options like contrib or non-free):

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't seem to work.  I edited my original post to reflect that.